# Отображение нужного фрагмента при повороте экрана

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity-life-cycle

Почему то не грузит картинки, поэтому постараюсь описать словами. Приложение показывает список фильмов, три варианта сортировки в тулбаре. Первый и второй это HTTP Request. Третий это отображенние сохраненных данных из SQLite. При нажатии на пункт списка, пользователь проваливается во фрагмент с детальным описанием выбранного кино. Сейчас при нажатии на ячейку списка, в бандл сохраняются данные а во фрагменте с детальным описанием эти данные извлекаются.

Есть 1 активити.
Фрагмент 1 - отображает список, содержимое отображается исходя из запроса, который нажал пользователь в тулбаре запрос1 и запрос2.
Фрагмент 2 - отображает список данных из SQLite. 
Списки Фрагмента 1 и Фрагмента 2 визуально одинаковые.

По нажатию на item любого из списка, пользователь проваливается во фрагмент 3, где отображаются более детальные данные выбранной ячейки. Работает кнопка Назад, поэтому фрагмент со списком идет в backStack.

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь попадал на нужный фрагмент при повороте экрана.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DetailedFragment detailedFragment;
private final String DETAILED_FRAGMENT_TAG = "detailedFragmentTag";
String path = "";
Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("list_fragment_tag");

        if (fragment instanceof FavouritesFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_list,
                    new FavouritesFragment().getInstance("favourite"), "list_fragment_tag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (fragment instanceof DetailedFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_list,
                    new DetailedFragment(), "list_fragment_tag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_list,
                    new ListFragment().getInstance("sort"), "list_fragment_tag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    }

    else {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_list,
                new ListFragment().getInstance("sort"), "list_fragment_tag");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }


}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("state_saving", "Inside activity saveInstanceState");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    if(outState != null && outState.getString(Contract.STATE_KEY) != null) {
        switch (outState.getString(Contract.STATE_KEY)) {

            case "popular":
                Log.d("state_saving", "Inside case Popular");

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_list, new ListFragment().getInstance("popular"));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case "sort":
                Log.d("state_saving", "Inside case Sort");

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_list, new ListFragment().getInstance("sort"));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case "favourite":
                Log.d("state_saving", "Inside case Favourite");

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_list, new FavouritesFragment().getInstance("favourite"));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case "detailed":
                Log.d("state_saving", "Inside case Detailed");

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_list, new DetailedFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d("state_saving", "Inside Else");

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_list, new ListFragment().getInstance("sort"));
        //new Handler().post( () -> fragmentTransaction.commit());
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //Checking for number of opened fragments
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        //Just closing current fragment
        fm.popBackStack();
        //Go to previous fragment
        goToPreviousFragment(fm);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Checking fragments and sending us on previous fragment
 *
 * @param fragmentManager - we can use method to get all current open fragments in back stack
 */
private void goToPreviousFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    for (Fragment fragment : fragmentManager.getFragments()) {
        if (fragment.getArguments().getString("path") != null) {
            path = fragment.getArguments().getString("path");
            switch (path) {
                case "sort":
                    openFragment(new ListFragment().getInstance("sort"), fragmentTransaction);
                    break;
                case "favourite":
                    openFragment(new FavouritesFragment().getInstance(""), fragmentTransaction);
                    break;
                case "popular":
                    openFragment(new ListFragment().getInstance("popular"), fragmentTransaction);
                    break;
                default:
                    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void openFragment(Fragment fragment, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_list, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Большое спасибо за любую подсказку или совет!

Comment: Если фрагменты визуально одинаковые, то вам не нужны два фрагмента, нужно в одном организовать логику, откуда брать данные, источник данных можно сохранять куда-нибудь в преференсы. То есть при отображении фрагмент "смотрит" в преференсах, откуда получать данные и в соответствии с этим к списку подключается нужный адаптер. при измении источника информация перезаписывается в преференсах. Соответственно и решать проблему перехода назад не нужно.

Comment: @pavlofff это только списки визуально одинаковые, а фрагмент с детальной информацией другой. Притом , когда пользователь находится на фрагменте с детальной инфой, фрагмент со списком находится в стаке